# Is there a way to revert to an earlier version of a commit in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

So I had created some files and made changes to other ones. Later on, I accidentally (I think) ran hg uncommit and hg revert. I'm not sure if that's the cause of the issue but a couple hours down the line, I check back into my branch and notice the files I created were gone. I'm wondering, is there a way to "rewind" back to an earlier version of the commit I have? (A version that would have those files still there). Thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean to find an earlier version of a file? Or did you literally mean an earlier version of the commit itself?

Answer (score 0):

Read `hg help up`, find "good" changeset and update WD to it